# html2canvas : how to choose a part of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, var, html2canvas

With html2canvas the screenshot start always at the top left of the body.
But I need to capture only a part of the body.
Could it be possible to introduce a variable to define a "left and top" to make just a small screenshot of the middle of the body?
I do not know much about the programming... and I'm completely lost!
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the identity of a screen element (e.g. `#container`) to the html2canvas function.  For example:

```js
$('#goButton').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#container'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      $('#image').append(canvas);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #888888;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<div id="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et ex neque. Vivamus vulputate libero magna, quis porttitor libero faucibus eu. Aenean pharetra eleifend leo nec varius. In facilisis enim quis tellus egestas, ut euismod orci eleifend. Vestibulum
  eget enim dapibus, sollicitudin ante a, bibendum purus. Fusce nec condimentum sapien. Aliquam lacus mauris, iaculis iaculis elit vel, tincidunt dapibus neque.</div>
<br>
<button id="goButton">Snap</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="image"></div>
```

Just position the element wherever you want it.  You should note that html2canvas doesn't actually do a screen shot - it actually renders the element (and all child elements and CSS), so you can't just specify an area of the screen.